# Custom fonts with @font-face only loads last

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

In my `project.less` file I have the following fonts loading:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_medium.woff) format('woff');
    //font-style: normal;
    font-weight: medium;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_text.woff) format('woff');
    //font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_thin.woff) format('woff');
    //font-style: normal;
    font-weight: thin;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_extrathin.woff) format('woff');
    //font-style: normal;
    font-weight: extrathin;
}
```

But it always load only one font, and it's the last one in the order I write them. In this case, every font on my app is extrathin, even tho their weight is normal. If I write the medium last, every font will be medium.

In the chrome network console I can see it always loads only one font.

Comment: are you specifying the `font-weight: value` property when assigning the font to your html elements? So, if you want all `<h1>` tags to be medium then `font-weight: medium`?

Comment: It does not change anything, since the chrome network console shows my only the last font file being downloaded. But the default should be the font-weight: normal, anyway.

Comment: @GiovaniBarcelos Some of the font weights (medium, thin, extrathin) you've declared here don't exist. So fix that up first. Having the same font-family name across the set is fine. Assign a number to each font's weight, medium > 500; text > normal or 400; thin > 300 or 200; extrathin > 200 or 100. I would then sort them from lightest to boldest. And include the "font-style:normal" property. Then when you want to use your font it should be as simple as; h1 {font:500 21px/1.2 'Myriad Set Pro', sans-serif;} p {font: 400 14px/1.2 'Myriad Set Pro', sans-serif;}, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this locally and from my results i can say that it is definitely because of the value you've assigned each of the "font-weight" properties.

These do not exist:

- medium
- thin
- extrathin

**Change them to an appropriate weight and it will work correctly.**
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

The only one that looks correct is the one set to 'normal' so it is interesting that the browser (i tested it in chrome) always loads in the last one declared...

Answer (score 0):

Well they all have the same name. So, as **cascading** style sheets tend to do... the last declaration is the one that takes precedence.

So.... change that and adjust font **names**.....

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Medium';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_medium.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Normal';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_text.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Thin';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_thin.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Extra Thin';
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Myriad-Apple-Text/myriad-set-pro_extrathin.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If you need to call a *different* font file for each face (thin, normal, extra thin, etc) then you need to specify the actual *font name* rather than relying on the `font-weight` property. Font-weight will only choose designated weights within the *same* font file.

So in the CSS rather than adjusting `font-weight` you would change the `font-family`

```
.p { font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Normal'; }
h1 { font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Medium'; }
.caption { font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro Thin'; }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way? I got these files from Apple website and they use only one global font-family declaration "Myriad Set Pro", even tho they use different files.

Comment: [Look again at Apple](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3n4CO.jpg).. they actually declare both separate names, and the same name. I can't argue with Apple's use, but I suspect they declare both because using the same name may only work on their device browsers since they control them. And they use both the eot and woff formats. But realistically, no. I'm not 100% certain. I know separate names *will* work though.